# Fix "[P2P0]WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received" in systemd file

Tags: monerod, daemon

I receive the error "[P2P0]WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received" while running my node. I know how to fix it in the command line when running manually with "DNS_PUBLIC=tcp://1.1.1.1 ./monerod" (which is odd because my dns is set to 1.1.1.1 anyway) but how can I fix it in the systemd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `Environment=DNS_PUBLIC=tcp://1.1.1.1` before the `ExecStart` line.